# How can I transfer text in Ukrainian to microdata?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, encoding, utf

I have an incomprehensible problem. I'm making an ASP.NET site and I want to stretch microdata to my site.
I have the following microdata for HTML code

```
@model ListPlatformsVM

@section Microdata {
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@@context": "https://schema.org/",
            "@@type": "BreadcrumbList",
            "itemListElement": [
                {
                    "@@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": "1",
                    "name": "@Model.str",
                    "item": "@Url.GetRouteUrl(EReviewerRoute.HomePage)"
                },
                {
                    "@@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": "2",
                    "name": "тестовий текст",
                    "item": "@Url.GetRouteUrl(EReviewerRoute.Platforms)"
                }
            ]
        }
    </script>
}
```

As you can see, I am passing the @Model.str variable from the model to the microdata. str is of type string (UTF-16). By breakpoints it is clear that the text in str is normal, but I get this result

[image]

Instead of my text in Ukrainian, strange characters are displayed `&#x442;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;`
There are a couple of other things that might help:

1. If you enter the Ukrainian text not through a variable, then everything is displayed normally
2. English text is displayed normally anyway

I want to display Ukrainian text using a variable passing it to the html code. Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`HtmlHelper.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method:

> Wraps HTML markup in a `HtmlString`, without HTML-encoding the specified value.

```
"name": "@Html.Raw(Model.str)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!)
Can you please tell what exactly the HtmlHelper.Raw method does?

Comment: @KostenetskiyStanislav was glad to help! If answer works for you - please mark it as accepted one.  P.S. Updated answer with quote from the docs - basically it does not perform html encoding on the string.